# SSH package for PHP?

Tags: php, windows, linux, ssh, natty

Ok this may seem like a very, *very* awkward question but here's my problem:

I need to be able to SSH to my site while at the library at my school but the only thing is that it NEVER works if I try to FileZilla it or puTTy it. I am not even using port 22 rather a separate port. Still it seams as if it is blocked.

I was wondering if I could use some package that I can add to my admin section on my site so I can ssh to my site directly from the browser (Also my school uses windows so doing ctrl+x in nano doesn't work.

I would preferably use PHP, as I can not use any other Server Side language (technical reasons) and I am pretty noob to websites and stuff, this is my first project as such.

Comment: Have you tried using port 80 for your SSH server?  Some firewalls do deep packet inspection, so this would probably not work in those cases, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has an excellent built-in SSH package (via pecl): https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

If you don't already have it, here are installation instructions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.intro.php

Comment: sorry, I don't understand how to install this as I am not too good with BASH and I am just getting into the tech world. Is it possible that you could write out instructions for installation for both packages? My root directory it /var/www thanks a million in advance as this would fix my issue permanently!

Comment: *include, write out sounds impolite :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [phpSecLib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  It implements the SSH protocol in PHP and is pretty common for this type of thing.

There are others available too if you search for something like "PHP SSH client"

Comment: No it doesn't require any extensions but mcrypt and gmp/bcmath are advisable to have for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to run commands on your own server. Installing an SSH library for PHP will not help you in that regard, unless you ssh from your server to itself. How about using a [php web shell](http://code.google.com/p/php-web-shell/)?

You'll have to make sure to secure it but it should allow you to run any commands you need within the browser.

Comment: This seems like it but um how would I implement this - I mean I found http://php-web-shell.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ and I am not sure WHERE to save these files? I mean I have a folder called admin in my root directory, would placing them here in a folder known as shell be fine and then which file would I need to open to ssh to my own server? Sorry if this seams to newby-ish

Comment: You'll need to download all of the files and keep them in the directory structure they are in, then copy those to the server. You can put them in any directory you want, just remember to control access to that folder via password or something else. If the admin folder is protected, use that. Then point your browser to the directory/client.php and start typing your commands.

Comment: `guest@php-web-shell:~ $  ` and when i enter my user it throws a lot of errors

Comment: <br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Non-static method Req::getVar() should not be called statically in <b>/var/www/admin/ssh/exec.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Non-static method Req::getVar() should not be called statically in <b>/var/www/admin/ssh/exec.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Non-static method phpShell::execPHP() should not be called statically in <b>/var/www/admin/ssh/exec.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
<br />

Comment: <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in <b>/var/www/admin/ssh/lib/shell.php(46) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>1</b><br /> as such I am receiving errors

Answer (score 0):

The connection from your school to the Internet is probably protected by a firewall.

In the easiest case the workstations in your school have direct access to the Internet but the firewall blocks connections to most ports. If this is the case you can try running `sshd` on port 80, the port used for HTTP.

In a more complicated case the workstations must pass through a HTTP proxy in order to access web pages. Apparently [Putty allows connecting to an SSH server through a HTTP proxy](http://meinit.nl/using-putty-and-an-http-proxy-to-ssh-anywhere-through-firewalls), you just have to [configure it correctly](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-proxy).

None of this requires PHP modules as the connections are made directly to `sshd`.